Page Header Crystal Report
I have a question about using formula field. So I want to generate a report that display dynamic. So I create a table. which is contain with some data depending on the seqno of my data.
Here is the example of my data:



val
seq




ABC1
1


ABC2
2


ABC3
3


ABC4
4



So here is what I did. I create per formula field. seqno1, seqno2, seqno3 and seqno4.
Each formula has a condition like this.
IF {Database.seq} = "1" THEN
   {Database.val}
Else

and the result is not displaying
PAGE HEADER | ABC1     | ABC2     |  ABC3     | ABC4     |
            | -------- | -------- | --------  | -------- |
DETAILS     |          |          |           |          |
            |          |          |           |          |
            |          |          |           |          |
            |          |          |           |          |

This is what I wanted to achieve btw I'm using crystal report in visual studio.
